# checkbox value on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 checkboxes and one button. Each of the checkboxes have different values when I click one any of the checkboxes and then click on the button I want that value from the checkbox to be shown so if I click on 2 of the checkboxes and then click the button I want those two's checkboxes values even if I click three of the checkboxes and click the button I want all three of there values if any one could help that would be great

thanks

Comment: Questions in Stackoverflow should contains your code effort otherwise it consider as off-topic. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code.

```
var checked = [];
$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
    $.each($("input[type='checkbox']:checked"), function(){            
        checked.push($(this).val());
    });
    console.log(checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## You can try below code.

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <form id="frm1" method="post">
      <input type="checkbox" class="test"  value="check1">
      Check1
      <input type="checkbox" class="test" value="check2">
      Check2
      <input type="checkbox" class="test"  value="check3">
      Check3
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="submit" class="button" />
    </form>
        
    <script>    
    var checked = [];
    jQuery(function() {
    
        jQuery("#frm1").submit(function() { alert('enter');
            jQuery("input.test[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
                alert(jQuery(this).val());
                checked.push(jQuery(this).val());
            });
            console.log(checked);
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```